# Delete relationship and object from context in NSManagedObject deinit

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a `NSManagedObject` with a to many relationship looking like this:

```
class Foo: NSManagedObject {

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).model.context

    @NSManaged var something: NSSet

    // Some setup etc.
}
```

When I'm deleting this object from the context, I'd like to delete `something` as well and tried doing so using `deinit` in the class `Foo`:

```
deinit {
    print(something.count) // prints 0

    something.forEach { context.deleteObject($0) }
}
```

When I delete an instance of `Foo`, `deinit` will be called but somehow the relation with `something` is lost before `deinit` is called. Is there a way to delete `something` using `deinit` instead of deleting it separately and manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the cascade delete rule on the relationship is for. Set it in the model view in Xcode.

Comment: I've googled and tried so many things for so long and the solution was simple... Thanks a lot.